# make image height be the 1/4 of the window's height

Tags: javascript, css, image, responsive-design, height

I try to make an image's height to always be the 1/4 of the window's height, based on responsive design and [fluid images](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images)

The image is a random image picked up by the database, so I dont know if its gonna be elongated or not.

This is what I got untill now

```
//after the path of the image is randomly collected with websockets
elem = document.createElement("img");
 elem.id="frontimage";
 elem.setAttribute("height", window.innerWidth/4+'px');

document.getElementById("icon").appendChild(elem);  

//this is triggered after window.onresize (see below)-in case the browser window is scaled
function img_adjust( img ) {
 var beholdItsTheNewHeight = window.innerWidth/4;
img.style.height  = beholdItsTheNewHeight  + 'px';
}

window.onresize = function() {
img_adjust( document.getElementById('frontimage') );
}


<div id="icon"  ></div>
```

(based on the anser by migf1, from [here](http://www.insomnia.gr/topic/506509-div-%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%B6%CE%B5%CE%B9-height-%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%B1-%CE%BC%CE%B5-%CF%84%CE%BF-%CF%85%CF%88%CE%BF%CF%82-%CE%BF%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%82/) , sorry its Greek)

And that's it. Works fine , if you just open a browser and the browser expands to the whole screen.

*Problems*

-I simply cannot align the image to the center of its container. I tried `margin, padding, float, position:absolute`. Nothing works

-If I start scaling the browser's window (simply dragging one corner) the image's height does not "follow". Resizes, but not actually in 1/4 of screen's height.

-If I open a browser and it's not expanding to the whole screen, the image's height not scale to the 1/4 of screen's height.

Any advise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use css property `#icon{ text-align: center;}` on the container DIV to center the image horizontally within the DIV. Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/2vxmX/

Comment: I can't reproduce the other two issues, when you resize the window the image changes height accordingly

Comment: Yes, I know, maybe because you cant have websockets in js fiddle (or can you?). I guess this works fine when the image is just one, pre-loaded image. In my case, the image changes with `body onload`. But, even then, why `window.resize` does not work?I dont get it

Comment: Hey, one more thing. I just put `elem.setAttribute("height", "40%");` And its not working. Why is that?Any advise? Thanks again